# What is the boost factor of a should in a bool_query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a newbie to Elasticsearch and couldn't find the answer to this in the online docs.

For elasticsearch 7.6 I have a `bool` with a `must` and a `should`. As I wanted the should part causes those results to be boosted.

However, what I can't find is what the default boost factor is when a should is matched? Is it possible to tweak this default boost factor?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch will calculate score for the individual queries in should clause and it will sum those two scores to get to a document's overall score. As a result, a document matching all should clauses will get a higher score and will  be ranked at the top.

You can boost individual clauses(queries) in should clause